# Apache not recognizing .htaccess authorization directives

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a Ubuntu running an Apache 2.2 webserver, and I'd like to password protect a directory that I'm serving, with all of its files and subdirectories, and be given a security prompt

Here's what I have in the virtual server web directory I'd like to protect:

```
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/dev/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I also have a valid .htpasswd file in `/home/dev`.  After researching a bit on serverfault, I learned that it may be necessary to give file and directory ownership to the owner of the apache process, which I did.

But at every time I try this, the website in this directory has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without showing us your complete apache configuration, it will be difficult to determine exactly the cause of your problem.

Anyway, I think you need to look at [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive. You need to allow at least `AuthConfig`. You can for simplicity allow `ALL`. Don't forget to reload/restart your apache server after the changes.

Comment: Correct, to use .htaccess I would have had to use the AllowOverride directive from within http.conf.  Thanks, this helped me get to the answer